# unable to properly load saved state most views cannot be shown

Tags: vtk, paraview

Disclaimer: I am a beginner to paraview, so apologies if the terms i am about to say are not correct.

I created a paraview session with multiple extract blocks, clips, slices, calculators, streamlines, etc. Each operation has a scalar or vector quantity that is being shown. Let’s refer to these operation as views. I saved this state as a .pvsm file using the “File > Save State”, and closed paraview. When I wanted to open the session again, i loaded in this saved state but noticed that most of the views (slices, clips, etc.) had no “eye” symbol beside it-- i could not click “Show” to see that view, making that view essentially useless. It looks like only the top level views in the pipeline had an “eye” beside the item.

How do i see the views without an “eye” beside them? Is there a way to save a paraview state such that all the views can be seen when loaded. One workaround i found is to hit “Show all” in paraview before saving the state. This way when i load the state all the views are loaded and all the pipeline items have an “eye” beside them. But i must be doing something wrong if i am doing it like this; there is probably something i am missing.

I am running paraview 5.10.1 on linux on 8 cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug and has fixed in the recently released 5.11.

ref: [issue #21381](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/issues/21381)